# Daniel’s use of עָמַד and קוּם

Tags: hebrew, daniel, linguistics

> Daniel 7:24 KJV
> [24] And the ten horns out of this kingdom are ten kings that shall **arise** (קוּם): and another shall **rise** (קוּם) after them; and he shall be diverse from the first, and he shall subdue three kings.

> Daniel 8:23 KJV
> [23] And in the latter time of their kingdom, when the transgressors are come to the full, a king of fierce countenance, and understanding dark sentences, shall **stand up** (עָמַד).

As seen above, the author of Daniel uses two different words when talking about kings “arising”. However, קוּם is only present in the Aramaic section (chapters 2-7) whereas עָמַד is present in only the Hebrew section (chapters 8-12).

Both *seem* to have the same meaning. Why then does the author use different words when describing essentially the same thing? What are the differences between the two words?

Comment: (329957) Perhaps a prince can be "enthroned" and "crowned"  and mean the same thing.  Or perhaps a person can be both "Lord" and "King" simultaneously.  There is no deeper meaning either way.

Answer (score 1):

They are different words because they are different languages!  Specifically

- Dan 7 is in Aramaic and thus קוּם is an Aramaic word.
- Dan 8 is in Hebrew and thus עָמַד is a Hebrew word.

This question is like asking the difference between "arise" (in English) and "entstehen" in German - both mean much the same thing but one is German and the other English.

In Dan 7:24 the word קוּם (qum, Aramaic); and the word עָמַד (amad, Hebrew) mean much the same thing - to arise or be established.

Comment: קוּם is the Aramaic equivalent to קוּם.  https://biblehub.com/hebrew/6966.htm